# Asp.Net MVC 3 formcollection losing data after submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, formcollection

I have a Asp.Net MVC 3 app and after I click on my submit button I want to validate the info passed in the formcollection argument.. and if it's not valid I return a jSon.. but after that my formcollection always returns null

this happens in chrome and FFox.. in IE it works fine

my view:

```
<li id="opc-register" class="section allow">
    <div id="checkout-step-register" class="step a-item" style="display: none;">
        <form id="co-register-form" action="">
        <div id="checkout-register-load">
            @Html.Action("OpcRegisterForm", "Checkout")
        </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Register.init('#co-register-form', '@(storeLocation)checkout/OpcSaveRegister/'); 
        </script>
        <div class="buttons" id="register-buttons-container">                           
            <button type="button" class="paymentmethodnextstepbutton" onclick="Register.save()">
                <span>@T("Common.Continue")</span>

            </button>

            <span class="please-wait" id="register-please-wait" style="display: none;">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax_loader_small.gif")"
    alt="@T("Common.LoadingNextStep")" title="@T("Common.LoadingNextStep")" />
                @T("Common.LoadingNextStep")</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OpcSaveRegister(FormCollection form)
{

    var registerModel = PrepareRegisterModel();

    registerModel.Email = form["Email"];
    registerModel.FirstName = form["FirstName"];
    ...

    if (TryValidateModel(registerModel))
    {
       ....
    }

    //If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Json(new
    {
        update_section = new UpdateSectionJsonModel()
        {
            name = "register",
            html = RenderPartialViewToString("OpcRegister", registerModel)
        },
        goto_section = "register"
    });
}
```

Comment: How would you use List values which iterates? The strongly typed model doesn't support the List<> values. This is why, with no option, have to use FormCollection.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use FormCollection on posts with MVC. Use a strongly typed ViewModel that contains all of the properties that can be submitted in your form on a post.

For example you could have a class like :

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

And in your view you'd set these properties with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
```

and then for your Action you'd have

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OpcSaveRegister(RegisterViewModel registerModel)
{
    //...
}
```